# Ошибка "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token"

Tags: c++

Давно изучал `С++` и вот нужно помочь другу. Ошибка и код прилагаются.
Юзаю `cpp.sh`:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  /*std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  getline (std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
  std::cout << "KAPEZ";*/

  float sqr (float fl1, float fl2){
    //float s = (fl1 * fl2)/2;
    return  (fl1 * fl2)/2;
  };

  //std::cout << sqr (2, 3)
}
```

Ошибка:

> In function 'int main()': 16:35: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Comment: А что такое `cpp.sh`?

Comment: Вложенные функции можно делать в gcc (не ++).

Comment: @avp, https://habrahabr.ru/post/149513/ :-)

Comment: @PinkTux, ну, кресты ... макросы из классов ... а ведь в начале была здравая идея, которая потом сменилась бредом, охватившим массы.

Answer (score 4):

Вынесите ваш `sqr` за пределы `main` - в С++ нельзя вкладывать функции друг в друга.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;


float sqr (float fl1, float fl2){
    //float s = (fl1 * fl2)/2;
    return  (fl1 * fl2)/2;
  };


int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  getline (std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
  std::cout << "KAPEZ";


  std::cout << sqr (2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! ПОМОГЛО

Comment: На самом деле можно вложить определение функции в другую функцию. Для этого есть как минимум два способа: 1. функция-член в локальном классе. 2. лямбда-функция.

Comment: @alexolut это не прямо то, что хотел сделать автор вопроса. То, что хотел сделать автор (вложить именнованную функцию, не являющуюся методом класса) сделать на C++ нельзя.